# Qualtrics - hide language bar for certain groups OR set language based on response

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

I am programming a survey in Qualtrics for 3 populations (A, B, and C).

Population A and B should have the option to select their preferred language, but Population C shouldn't have this option.

I either need to figure out how to only display the language menu to certain populations based on embedded data, or use a screener question that is only displayed to Population A and B, which will determine the language.

Either of these scripts will hide the language bar in general, but I can't figure out how to hide for certain groups but not others

Option 1: **.LanguageSelectorContainer {display:none;}**

Option 2:  **#Q_lang{display:none;}**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Those options are CSS, not scripts. You'll need to write a JavaScript to selectively hide the Language drop-down.

Comment: Thanks very much @T.Gibbons for getting back to me! Could you (or anyone else) point me in the right direction for figuring out how to write that JavaScript? As you may have guessed from my question, I'm out of my element here. My programming skills are... limited. Thanks (again) in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with JavaScript by adding the following to the JavaScript for a question on each page you want it hidden on:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var hidden = "${e://Field/hideLanguage}";
    if(hidden == "true"){
        $$('.LanguageSelectorContainer')[0].hide();
    }else{
        $$('.LanguageSelectorContainer')[0].show();
    }

});
```

This makes use of piped text to pipe the value of an embedded data element in to the script. Obviously this variable, and the check being done in the if() statement will need to be adjusted to suit your use case.

If you want this to be active on every page of the survey, you can put it inside html script tags in the header source, which can be found in the Advanced Look and Feel menu.